# Adding Flask-Restful resource raises 'str' object has no attribute '__name__'

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-requests, flask-restful

I am trying to add route to flask app in python 3. But I am getting error at following line saying **AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__name__'**

> api.add_resource('/todo/api/v1.0/tasks', methods=['GET'])

My code snippet is as follows

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify,abort,make_response,request,url_for
from flask_restful import Api
from referme.common import db
app = Flask(__name__)
#db.init(app)
from referme.resources.tasks import Tasks
api = Api(app)
api.add_resource('/refer-me/api/v1.0/tasks', methods=['GET'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't passing the `Tasks` Resource to `add_resource`.

The [docs](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#a-minimal-api) say

```
api.add_resource(HelloWorld, '/')
```

so I think your invocation should be

```
api.add_resource(Tasks, '/refer-me/api/v1.0/tasks', methods=['GET'])
```